Change of variable for complex pushforward-measure
Let $X$ and $Y$ be measurable spaces. Let $\mu$ be a complex measure on $X$. Let $f_*\mu$ be the pushforward-measure (i.e., $(f_*\mu)(B)=\mu\left(f^{-1}(B)\right)$). Let $X\xrightarrow{f}Y\xrightarrow{g}\mathbb C$ be measurable functions such that $g$ is integrable with respect to $f_*\mu$. Then is it true that
\begin{equation}
\int g\,d(f_*\mu)=\int(g\circ f)\,d\mu\quad\text{?}
\end{equation}
I know that it is true if $\mu$ is a positive measure and I tried to extend it to the complex case, but I could not do it.

If $\mu$ is a complex measure and $F$ a (say real-valued for starters) function on $X$, then how is $\int_X F,d\mu$ defined?

@peek-a-boo. My definition is $\int F,d\mu=\int F\cdot\frac{d\mu}{d|\mu|},d|\mu|$, where $|\mu|$ is a total variation of $\mu$ and $\frac{d\mu}{d|\mu|}$ is a Radon-Nikodym-derivative.

Any complex measure is a linear combination of four finite positive measures.

@geetha290krm. It is true that $\int g,d(f_\mu)=\left(\int g,d((f_\mu)r^+)-\int g,d((f\mu)r^-\right)+i\left(\int g,d((f\mu)i^+-\int g,d(f\mu)i^-\right)$ and $\int(g\circ f),d\mu=\left(\int g,d(f\mu_r^+)-\int g,d(f_\mu_r^-)\right)+i\left(\int g,d(f_\mu_i^+)-\int g,d(f_\mu_i^-)\right)$. But the problem is that I cannot prove $(f_\mu)r^+=f*(\mu_r^+)$ etc.

What those four finite positive measures are does not come into the picture. It is just a question writing four equations and taking  a linear combination.
